# $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^22^{n-k}$, deriving a closed form

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I was asked to find a closed formula for $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^22^{n-k}$$

I know the answer (using wolfram alpha) but I don't know how to solve it myself. Could anyone give me a hand?

I thought maybe saying that $$2^{n-k}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}$$

And then we get: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^22^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}$$

but that seems to make the problem even worse, I don't think that's the way.

by the way, the correct answer (according to wolfram alpha) is $-n^2-4n+6(2^n-1)$

Comment: See [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with:
$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} z^k = \frac{z^{n + 1} - 1}{z - 1}
$$
Note that if you have $A(z) = \sum_k a_k z^k$ then:
$$
z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} A(z) = \sum_k k a_k z^k
$$
That should be enough of a hint to get your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^nk^22^{n-k}=2^n\sum_{k=0}^nk^2\left(\frac12\right)^k$$

Let us find $\displaystyle S=\sum_{k=0}^nk^2r^k$

$\displaystyle\implies r\cdot S=\sum_{k=0}^nk^2r^{k+1}$

$\displaystyle\implies S-r\cdot S=\sum_{k=1}^n[k^2-(k-1)^2]r^{k+1}-n^2r^{n+1}$

$\displaystyle S(1-r)=-n^2r^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)r^{k+1}$

Now, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)r^{k+1}$ can be managed using Arithmetico-geometric series [I](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series#Finite_Sum), [II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence)

**Reference** : [Finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Finite_difference_methods)